# Scroll in div moves content

Tags: css

Being new to the use of div, I am facing some problems which I hope you can help with.

CSS

```
#wrapperBox {
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    border-color: #f3a538;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #cccccc;
}

.rullerContent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 465px;
    border: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapperBox">
  <div class="rullerContent">
    Here is a lot of text, so vertical scroll will appear.....
  </div>
</div>
```

My problems:

1) The scroll pushes the other content of the page. Can I in some way dedicate space for the scrollbar or hide it (even better), but still get scrolling function?

2) Can I define the height to be "to the bottom of the browser window", so it appears as the text just keeps coming, without having the vertical scroll on the entire page?

Hope you can help and I have been specific.

Regards

Comment: have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: Your second point is not clear. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can 'hide' the scrollbar and still have the default behavour (using the mouse wheel) by adding some padding to the right of `.rullerContent`.

You can use `height:100%` to make your elements take up 100% of the document screen.

I've changed `box-sizing` to `border-box` for `.wrapperBox` so that the border width is included in the height:

```
#wrapperBox {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    border-color: #f3a538;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.rullerContent {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    border: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mfump/)

Of course you'll not be able to click and/or drag the scrollbar area anymore.. Because you can't see it.

Comment: Thanks. It solved the hiding og the scroll bar and the pushing of the other content. But the content of the .rullerContent is not showing in Firefox, but does in Safari.

Comment: Seems to be working OK for me in Firefox? What version are you using?

Comment: Firefox 29.0 for IOS. But when I use the JSFiddle in Firefox it works. So it would seem that some of my coding may conflict? Firebug did not reveal any reasons

Comment: Disabling the "overflow:auto" in .rullerContent shows content in Firefox, but without inside scrolling

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the reason for that. Is it just Firefox on IOS that you run into issues with?